# Parsing Values in columns using TCL

Tags: regex, list, parsing, tcl

I have an output which looks like below

```
A  B  C


0  1  2
```

I have lot of coloumns due to which the o/p looks to have wrapped around. I am wondering a way to get the respective value if I parse the keys (A B or C)

Comment: Is that just an example or is your input really like that? Can the keys consist of multiple words joined by single space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering each key (i.e. alphabet) will have one value (i.e. numeral), then we can use the following way. (This might be a workaround to get what we need)

```
set input "A  B  C


0  1  2"

set alpha [ regexp -all -inline {[a-zA-Z]} $input]; #Match all alphabets
set numeric [ regexp -all -inline {\d} $input]; #Match all numeric values

#Using 'foreach' to loop both list at a same time.
foreach a $alpha n $numeric  { 
    puts "$a : $n"
}
```

If the pair is not equally distributed, (i.e either alphabet or numeric value is missing) then they will be assigned with empty string during the course of `foreach` loop execution.

If you want to get them in Key-Value pair then, we can make use of `dict` or `array` in tcl.

**Dictionary Implementation**

```
foreach a $alpha n $numeric  { 
   dict append test $a $n
}
puts "Whole dictionary  : [ dict get $test ]"
puts "Value of key A : [ dict get $test A ]"; #Getting value of key 'A'

dict for { a n } $test { 
    puts "Key : $a ==> Value : $n "
}
```

**Array Implementation**

```
foreach a $alpha n $numeric  { 
   set result($a) $n
}

puts "Whole array : [ array get result ]"
puts "Value of key A : $result(A) "#Getting value of key 'A'
foreach index [array names result] { 
    puts "Key : $index ==> Value : $result($index)"
}
```

Reference : [dict](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/dict.htm), [array](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/array.htm)